# Python Time out error on swapping list elements for minimum swaps 2

Tags: python

Trying to swap values to make sequantial list (from HackerRank problem - Minimum Swaps 2) and code is working for most of the test cases but timing out on large data set. Is there any better way to write below code:

So initial list 4 3 1 2 should be 1 2 3 4 after minimum number of swaps.

```
# arr[] = 4 3 1 2 -> 
for i in range(len(arr), 0, -1):
    if i != arr[i-1]:
        arr[i-1], arr[arr.index(i)] = arr[arr.index(i)], arr[i-1]
        swap += 1
return swap
```

Comment: Call `arr.index(i)` once before the assignment. Otherwise, the assignment to `arr[i-1]` might change the index.

Comment: `arr.index(i)` is O(n), so doing that every time through the loop makes it an O(n^2) algorithm. Make a dictionary that maps every number to its index, and update it when you swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary to hold the indexes, rather than using `arr.index(i)` every time through the loop. When you perform a swap, update the indexes dictionary accordingly.

```
indexes = {el:i for i, el in enumerate(arr)}
for i in range(len(arr), 0, -1):
    if i != arr[i-1]:
        index = indexes[i]
        indexes[i] = i - 1
        indexes[arr[i-1]] = index
        arr[i-1], arr[index] = arr[index], arr[i-1]
        swap += 1
return swap
```

And even if you use `arr.index(i)`, you need to call it it once before swapping. The destination expressions on the left are evaluated sequentially, so the assignment to `arr[i-1]` might change the result of `arr.index(i)`, and you'll end up assigning to the wrong place when you assign to `arr[arr.index(i)]`.

Comment: I never thought in the way you explained. Thank you. Also does it mean that arr.index is costly operation when doing it on large dataset?

Comment: Yes, didn't you see my earlier comment about it being O(n)?

Comment: I did read it. Now its making it more sense to me when i compare both results side by side.

Answer (score -1):

A simpler solution to this would be to not use a dictionary or even bother with managing the indexes.

Just simply append to the end of the array the popped value from the beginning.

```
for i in range(len(arr), 0, -1):
    arr.append(arr.pop(0))
return arr
```

This simplifies the problem down to a one line loop using built in python functions.

Comment: This is an identity operation.

Comment: Yea I see how I did it on len(arr)... In the original code (which I copied from my hacker rank profile) it actually gives you a set number of swaps to preform. So I see how the modified version here misses that point. Though a simple edit to run -1 solves for exactly the problem in the question but not the greater problem. But the accepted doesn't solve for the greater problem either.

Comment: I didn't bother checking the accepted answer, since I'm on the phone, and also don't have a sheet of paper at hand. Yours was at least trivial to reason about.